# How To Create A Class Diagram From A Use Case

Tags: uml, class-diagram, use-case-diagram

Has anyone got any pointers or can help me with doing a class diagram from a Use Case Diagram? Its been a few years since i have done one and i am at a complete loss. [image: Use Case] Not sure how to link the image straight into the post.

I don't need anything extensive, just very simplistic

Comment: To make your image visible use the editors icon or place an ! in front of the reference. See my edit of your question.

Comment: It is amost certain that you'll not be able to go from a Use case diagram to a class diagram with the Use case diagram alone. Your case is a good example. You need the specification of what information the system should supply. This includes structure, content and behavior of the things/topics/issues relevant for the usecases. From these you can derive classes, relations operations and attributes. Userstories are a good start to derive Use cases and Classdiagrams. E.g. "For a user to login a name and password is needed". You'd derive a Class User with name, password and login() from this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A class diagram and use case diagrams are quite different really, they detail different aspects of your design.  Think of a use case diagram as something you start off with explaining your system -- a high level interaction between human (various roles in your business/org) to system they touch or use.  Then those systems are connected with other systems.

Now a class diagram is quite a bit more detailed it shows the objects or components within a specific use case bubble!  Sometimes those classes are database tables, sometimes they are objects.  So a class diagram is quite a bit more detailed.

So if you want to go from use case diagram to a class diagram, start with the first system in your use case and detail the components for that item.  Classes can represent database tables or actual system objects, it depends on your need and how detailed you want to be to relay your design.  Go as deep as necessary to relay your points so who ever is going to build/review your system understands the design.

Comment: Thank you elecstrat. Am i right in thinking that each bubble will be represented as a class in my class diagram?

Comment: Think of each bubble in a use case diagram as an "action" or "what can be done" in your system.  And the use case documents the actions that are related - together making up a specific use case.  Class diagram, however shows how the data is organized in your system, or objects that work with your data.  So you may have multiple classes that span bubbles and usually a bubble will have more then one class.  Think of class diagram as a structural view of your system, while use cases show what your system can do.

Answer (score 1):

Class diagrams allow you to *conceptualize your system* as a whole and visualize how the *different components of your system will interact with one another*. This class diagram will allow you to break your system down into manageable pieces, saving time in the long run since you will have a concrete understanding of how your system works before coding it up. Some *common questions to ask* when creating a class diagram are the following:

1. What classes do I need?
2. What functionality and information will these classes have?
3. How do they interact with one another?

For more information please refer to this article on [Medium](https://medium.com/@smagid_allThings/uml-class-diagrams-tutorial-step-by-step-520fd83b300b), they do a great job providing a tutorial on a class diagram walk-through.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Please consider accepting my answer if you found it helpful :)